# Is Unique build rule to check uniqueness on year only not whole datetime field ?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to validate combination of email and created using build rules such that created field's year is considered only for uniqueness.

```
$rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email', 'created'], 'invalid entry'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to do [custom validation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#using-custom-validation-rules)